Conditional Statement works but Why isn't my UI not updating it state?
I am working on a search widget to give recent searches when Textfield is empty and give recommendation of products with texteditingcontroller text when user typing simultaneously.I used chatgpt and gemini to make the code .My problem is conditional statement is working fine but the output of that statement is giving me error. I don't know how to grasp this error and lead from it. Can somebody explain why is this happening?
//code
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Searchscreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const Searchscreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<Searchscreen> createState() => _SearchscreenState();
}

class _SearchscreenState extends State<Searchscreen> {
  final TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  final List<String> items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
  List<String> filteredItems = [];
  Timer? _debounce;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    searchController.addListener(_onSearchChanged);
    filteredItems = items;
  }

  void _onSearchChanged() {
    if (_debounce?.isActive ?? false) _debounce!.cancel();
    _debounce = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
      setState(() {
        filteredItems = items
            .where((item) => item
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(searchController.text.toLowerCase()))
            .toList();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _debounce?.cancel();
    searchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: const Icon(Icons.menu),
        title: Text('Search'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
            child: Material(
              elevation: 5,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: searchController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                cursorColor: Colors.blue,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                  ),
                  hintText: "Search",
                  suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.blue),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.020),
          searchController.text.isEmpty
              ? Container()
              : filteredItems.isEmpty
                  ? Center(child: Text("No results found"))
                  : Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: filteredItems.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(filteredItems[index]),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
            ),
          );
      }
    }

//error
Lookup failed: filterItems in @methods in _SearchscreenState in package:buildup/src/Screens/Search/Searchscreen.dart
 
 When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
 #0      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:437:24)
 #1      ValueNotifier.value= (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:559:5)
 #2      TextEditingController.value= (package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:266:11)
 #3      EditableTextState._value= (package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:3531:23)
 #4      EditableTextState._formatAndSetValue (package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:4183:5)
 #5      EditableTextState.updateEditingValue (package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:3246:7)
 #6      TextInput._updateEditingValue (package:flutter/src/services/text_input.dart:2067:43)
 #7      TextInput._handleTextInputInvocation (package:flutter/src/services/text_input.dart:1903:29)
 #8      TextInput._loudlyHandleTextInputInvocation (package:flutter/src/services/text_input.dart:1803:20)
 #9      MethodChannel._handleAsMethodCall (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:571:55)
 #10     MethodChannel.setMethodCallHandler.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:564:34)
 #11     _DefaultBinaryMessenger.setMessageHandler.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/binding.dart:618:35)
 #12     _invoke2 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:344:13)
 #13     _ChannelCallbackRecord.invoke (dart:ui/channel_buffers.dart:45:5)
 #14     _Channel.push (dart:ui/channel_buffers.dart:135:31)
 #15     ChannelBuffers.push (dart:ui/channel_buffers.dart:343:17)
 #16     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPlatformMessage (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:750:22)
 #17     _dispatchPlatformMessage (dart:ui/hooks.dart:257:31)

 The TextEditingController sending notification was:
 TextEditingController#e7d9b(TextEditingValue(text: ┤a├, selection:
 TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 1, affinity: TextAffinity.downstream,
 isDirectional: false), composing: TextRange(start: -1, end: -1)))


do not reinvent the wheel with custom debounce timers, instead use already known solutions like stream transformers, something like this: https://gist.github.com/pskink/c4d3615d93ba77ef16016aaca21e0f77#file-foo_search-dart-L72

ok bro i get on with it
